# "stack smashing detected" error when calling a Fortran function from C

Tags: c, fortran, interop, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have an iterative linear solver written in Fortran, and would like to call it in C/C++, the source code can be found at

https://github.com/fangq/blit/

where the Fortran solver code is in `src/`. However, a simple C test code does not terminate properly and raises an error

```
**stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated**
```

before returning.

The C code can be found at

https://github.com/fangq/blit/blob/master/cpp/example/passdata.c
and the code is also listed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "blit_solvers.h"

int main(){
    BLQMRSolver qmr;
    int size=100;

    ZBLQMRCreate(&qmr,&size);
    ZBLQMRPrint(&qmr);

    qmr.nrhs=8;
    qmr.maxit=1000;
    qmr.state=-1;
    qmr.dopcond=1;
    qmr.isquasires=0;
    qmr.debug=1;

    ZBLQMRPrint(&qmr);
    return 1;
}
```

where I simply define a C-struct, pass it to Fortran to set initial values (`ZBLQMRCreate`), then, print the update values in Fortran (`ZBLQMRPrint`).

the C-struct is passed to the Fortran function with a Fortran prototype as

```
type, bind(c) :: BLQMRSolver
        integer(c_int) :: n, nrhs, maxit, state, dopcond, flag, iter, isquasires, debug
        real(c_double) :: qtol, droptol, res, relres ! convergence tolerance
        type (ILUPcond) :: ilu ! private ILU preconditioner
end type BLQMRSolver
```

The printing function does show the values are modified properly, however, the last line of the code triggered the above stack-smashing error. Even I comment out all lines below `ZBLQMRCreate`, I still got the same error. Valgrind gave me this message

```
==19135== Command: bin/passdata

*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
==19135== 
==19135== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
==19135==    at 0x6129E97: raise (raise.c:51)
==19135==    by 0x612B800: abort (abort.c:79)
==19135==    by 0x6174896: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:181)
==19135==    by 0x621FCD0: __fortify_fail_abort (fortify_fail.c:33)
==19135==    by 0x621FC91: __stack_chk_fail (stack_chk_fail.c:29)
==19135==    by 0x1099F5: main (passdata.c:21)
...
```

I tried to change the Fortran data structure ([`type BLQMRSolver`](https://github.com/fangq/blit/blob/master/src/blit_blqmr.f90#L48-L52)) to use `iso_c_binding`, and `c_int/c_double` for members, but still does not change anything.

any suggestion on how to fix this is appreciated!

commands to reproduce this error (need to install gfortran/gcc/lapack/umfpack first):

```
git clone https://github.com/fangq/blit.git
cd blit/src
make clean
make static
cd ../cpp/example
make
./bin/passdata
```

Comment: try to increase stack size first

Comment: "The c code can be found at ..." - *Please* don't do that. Stackoverflow questions should be 100% self contained. Meaning they should contain *all* necessary information directly in the question. This means you should *never* link to external resources as those may rot over time. Include the code directly *in* the question. No external links.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I bumped up stack size to 128MB, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, where did you see that error? my links are all tested and valid.

Comment: @FangQ You are linking to external sites instead of including everything directly in the question. That's the problem. Don't link to external sites that may disappear tomorrow. Doesn't matter if the link works today. You should put the contents *in the question* so it doesn't matter if the link exists tomorrow.

Comment: the link to this stack-overflow question may also disappear in the future, I don't see the point of why a post can not use external links, despite that I understand why it is preferred for SO.

Comment: anyhow, I embedded the c-code in addition to the link

Comment: According to this line in Fortran https://github.com/fangq/blit/blob/master/src/blit_blqmr.f90#L51 , the `BLQMRSolver` type has a component `ilu` of type `ILUPcond` as a value (not a pointer). But, this line in C/C++ https://github.com/fangq/blit/blob/master/include/blit_solvers.h#L26 has the corresponding field as a pointer (rather than a value)... is this possibly related to the problem?